# Erro no Spring Boot com time zone

Tags: java

Olá, quando rodo o programa o spring dá esse erro:
java.sql.SQLException: No timezone mapping entry for 'TimeZone'.
A minha dúvida mesmo é como coloco useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC na configuração do meu application.properties matendo o createDatabaseIfNotExist=true.
Minha configuração:
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_mvc?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root

## JPA

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.open-in-view= true
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings = false

## THYMELEAF

spring.thymeleaf.cache = false

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver desta forma:

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo_mvc?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root